# Prove that any positive semi-definite matrix is "nearly" invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

A positive semi-definite matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ is said to be $\eta$-invertible if there is an approximate inverse matrix $\Theta$ such that $$\max_{j,k}|(\Sigma\Theta-I)_{jk}|\leq\eta.$$

I am tasked with showing that any such $\Sigma$ is 1-invertible, but have no idea how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try the case where $A$ is diagonal. Maybe you can get the general case from that by diagonalizing $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\Sigma = U^T \Lambda U$ with $U$ orthogonal, $\Lambda= \operatorname{diag} ( \lambda_1,...,\lambda_m, 0,..0)$ real diagonal and the $\lambda_k \neq 0$.

Let $\Lambda^\dagger = \operatorname{diag} ( {1 \over \lambda_1},...,{1 \over \lambda_m}, 0,..0)$ (the Pseudo inverse) and
$\Theta = U^T \Lambda^\dagger U$. Then note that
$\Sigma \Theta = U^T \operatorname{diag} ( 1,...,1, 0,..0) U$.

Then $e_i^T \Sigma \Theta e_j = \sum_{k=1}^m [u_i]_k [u_j]_k$, where $u_i = U e_i$, $u_j = U e_j$.

If $i \neq i$, then $|\sum_{k=1}^m [u_i]_k [u_j]_k| \le \|u_i\|_2 \|u_j\|_2 = 1$, and if $i=j$,
$1-\sum_{k=1}^m [u_i]_k^2 = \sum_{k=m+1}^n [u_i]_k^2 \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.** Let $\Sigma=Q\operatorname{diag}(D,0)Q^T$ be an orthogonal diagonalisation, where $D$ is a positive diagonal matrix. Let $\Theta=\Sigma^+=Q\operatorname{diag}(D^{-1},0)Q^T$. Then both
\begin{aligned}
A&:=\Sigma\Theta&=Q\operatorname{diag}(I,0)Q^T\\
\text{and }B&:=I-\Sigma\Theta&=Q\operatorname{diag}(0,I)Q^T
\end{aligned}
are positive semidefinite. One can show that the diagonal elements of $A$ and $B$ are bounded above by $1$. The size of each off-diagonal element of $B$ can be estimated by considering the $2\times2$ principal minors of $B$.